# How do I cast ICollection<Subclass> to ICollection<BaseClass>?

Tags: c#

I have this model structure:

```
[Table("Image")]
public abstract class CBaseImage
{

    public int ID { get; set; }


    [Required]
    public string Extension { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(11)]
    [Required]
    public string OriginalUrl { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(11)]
    [Required]
    public string ThumbUrl { get; set; }

    public int OrderNumber { get; set; }
}




public class CNewBuildingLayoutImage : CBaseImage
{
    public int NewBuildingLayoutID { get; set; }
    public virtual CNewBuildingLayout NewBuildingLayout { get; set; }


    [AImageFormat(527, 584, false)]
    [MaxLength(11)]
    [Required]
    public string WH_527_584_Url { get; set; }


    [AImageFormat(304, 342, false)]
    [MaxLength(11)]
    [Required]
    public string WH_304_342_Url { get; set; }



}
```

and

```
[Table("NewBuildingLayout")]

public class CNewBuildingLayout
{

    public int ID { get; set; }
    //.........

    public virtual ICollection<CNewBuildingLayoutImage> Images { get; set; }

}
```

At some point I need to use `CNewBuildingLayout.Images` which is `ICollection<CNewBuildingLayoutImage>` AS `ICollection<CBaseImage>`,
but when I do:

```
(ICollection<CBaseImage>)someLayout.Images
```

I get:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet'1[Models.CNewBuildingLayoutImage]'
>   to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet'1[Models.CBaseImage]'.

I tried

```
  (ICollection<CBaseImage>)someLayout.Images.Cast<CBaseImage>()
```

with same result.

How do I cast `ICollection<Subclass>` to `ICollection<BaseClass>`?

Comment: This cannot be done. If you get `ICollection<CBaseImage>`, you would be able to call `Add` and pass some `CBaseImage` derived class that is not `CNewBuildingLayoutImage`.

Comment: I suppose you're right. If you write this as an answer I'll accept that

Comment: @Roman - You're wrong about your additional information. The type `ICollection<CNewBuildingLayoutImage>` is an in-memory collection and nothing to do with the records being stored in a database. The duplicate is correct.

Comment: @Enigmativity in chapter "Lazy Loading" here (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) is explained how property `public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }`  loads related Posts only when iterating thru it, unless I'm losing something

Comment: @Roman - Yes you are. The type is still an in-memory collection even if it lazily loads the data and all the normal casting rules apply.

Comment: It is a type safety violation, if this could work then you could add *another* class object that derives from CBaseImage.  Violating the guarantee that the HashSet only contains CNewBuildingLayoutImage objects.  You either have to create a hashet of CBaseImages or use a covariant interface type like IEnumerable<>.  IEnumerable is safe because it cannot modify the collection.

Comment: @Enigmativity thanks, you're right. I checked logs to database during debug and it gets all related data when just <i>accessing</> property for the first time, before iterating or whatever, which means when I need to use this property data is already loaded into memory from db. And article says: "first time the Posts navigation property is accessed". Type is in-memory collection, duplicate mark is valid.

Comment: @Hans Passant understood. Yes, this makes sense. Thanks for mentioning covariant interface, I'll keep that in mind